# Change angular2 select/option to ul/li binded to selection

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular2-template

I would like to change the following `select`, `option` tags to be a `ul`,`li` instead.

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedLanguage" name="selectedLanguage">
                    <option *ngFor="let lang of languages" [value]="lang">{{lang}}</option>
                </select>
```

Ideally it would be bootrap-friendly like:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
   <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

Can someone help please?
Thanks

**EDIT**:
If I just change `select` for `ul` and `option` for `li` I'd get

```
error_handler.js:49ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No value accessor for form control with name: 'selectedLanguage'
```

I guess the `[value]` tag is not valid on `li`, but I am not quite sure how to fix it

I need `[(ngModel)]="selectedLanguage"`  to be updated with the selected `li`

Comment: What's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewriting that should be as easy as:

```html
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li *ngFor="let lang of languages" (click)="selectedLanguage = lang">{{lang}}</li>
</ul>
```

---

> Working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/UifDT44QZdVvjyBHnjmo?p=preview) for example usage

Comment: It's not the same thing. This does not let me set the selected language on the `selectedLanguage` variable

Comment: You didn't tell us, that that's your goal - just assign it on click then.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use `[(ngModel)]="..."` with `<ul>`. This only works with components that provide a `ControlValueAccessor`. You need a component instantiated for the `<ul>` element that does support `ControlValueAccessor` to make this work.